# Box2D Raycast fraction is never zero?

Tags: libgdx, box2d, raycasting

Im trying to raycast from the bottom of a box downwards. When the box is in the floor, I'd imagine the raycast fraction value would be zero, but it always gives me 0.0149998665. To be honest, It is not logic-breaking at all, but it OCD's me alot, and I'm just wondering why this happens?

Added a little sketch to make it easier to visualize:

[image]

Comment: this is pure speculation, but perhaps the high, the line of shepe than it maintains, or the sum of both lines as this one above the other are not overlapped

Comment: The lines arent overlapped, but the lines are "imaginary", in the end the lines only exist to represent the objects, which have a real width and height, so if I start from the bottom of the shape and point down, if they are colliding it should still be 0, there shouldnt be those kinds of "margins", there should be no space between the objects...

Comment: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/gotchas#smallgap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polygons (and edges) in Box2D are kept at a tiny distance apart to help stability in the contact constraint solver. http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/gotchas#smallgap